# Zend Searching for serial numbers (strings not integers)

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have some search functionality currently working in which I can search for serial numbers aslong as they are integers.

For example this works fine.

Search for serials >= 352123 and <= 360000

What is the best approach for doing a similar search when serials can consist of a string?

For example:

> = '352123/230w' and <= '352123/250w'

I have my table set up as MyISAM to make use of fulltext search in the hope that this will help in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do string comparisons like this, but you have to be aware that it's using the lexical value. eg:

```
SELECT '352123/230w' <= '352123/250w';
-- returns 1

SELECT '352123/230w' <= '4';
-- also returns 1
```

Assuming that all of your serial numbers are formatted like this you could use string operations to split out the numbers, convert to integers, and sort based on those, however you're both introducing a lot of conversion overhead as well as throwing away your indexes, so it would be very slow/inefficient.

You could always add another field or two to store a numerical equivalent, ie. '352123/230w' stripped of non-numeric chars to 352123230 and use that for your sort, but it really depends on the formatting of all tracked serial numbers being consistent.

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunately there is a lot of different serial type formats stored within the same column so splitting the serials would not be an option. Is there a certain term for what I am trying to achieve that I could use to find further info on this?

Comment: @Mattvb91 yes, [Computed Indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-expressional.html). But, like most useful SQL features, MySQL does not support them.